# Combine Two List in to One In Python

Tags: python, list

## List of images negative_files

```
directory="/resources/data"

negative='Negative'
negative_file_path=os.path.join(directory,negative)

negative_files=[os.path.join(negative_file_path,file) for file in  os.listdir(negative_file_path) if file.endswith(".jpg")]

negative_files.sort()
```

## List of images positive_files

```
positive="Positive"

positive_file_path=os.path.join(directory,positive)

positive_files=[os.path.join(positive_file_path,file) for file in  os.listdir(positive_file_path) if file.endswith(".jpg")]

positive_files.sort()
```

I want to create another list all_files such that the even indexes contain the path to images with positive_files and  the odd indexes contain the path negative file.
Expected Output:

```
all_files[0]=positive_files[0] //image because 0th index of all_files is even.

all_files[1]=negative_files[0] //image because 1st index of all_files is odd.

all_files[2]=positive_files[1] //image because 2nd index of all_files is even.

all_files[3]=negative_files[1] //image because 3rd index of all_files is odd.
```

and so on...

## Here is a pseudo Code i tried for dummy numbers

```
a=[10,20,30]

b=[50,60,70,80,90,100,200]


m=len(a)

n=len(b)

l=m+n


i=j=k=0


c=[]

while i< l:

    if i%2==0:

        c[i]=a[j]

        j=j+1

    else:

        c[i]=b[k]

        k=k+1
print(c)
```

Error:Index out of range.

## So,my question how to create such a type of list?

Comment: Are the lengths of positive and negative files same ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

1. You cannot call `a[i]` on a list because your list is currently empty. You need to use the `list.append()` function to add items to the list.
2. You are not incrementing `i` in your while loop, which will trigger an infinite loop.
3. If the length of positive and negative files are same, your code will run. Else you need  some other logic to fill the gaps of indices. You can check if your current `j` or `k` is greater than `l` or `m` respectively and then add all the remaining elements of the bigger list to your final list.
   This is one of the possibility, it might differ according to your use case.

Comment: I have used the function list.append() to add items,it worked for the case. Also,I forgot to increment i there . Thanks

Comment: @PrabhakarMaity I have edited the answer to show one possible way in which you can tackle the unequal list problem. Is it okay?

Answer (score 0):

Your desired target of odd and even indices seems inappropriate for different lengths (which is responsible for the error) and ignoring more complex structure easily achieved with Python.

Take a look at the `zip` function and consider to build a list of tuples instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both lists have the same length

```py
import itertools
all_files = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(positive_files, negative_files)))
```

Comment: positive_files and negative_files are of different length. I stored them in variable lenP and lenN respectively.How to combine them now?

Comment: Then have a look at itertools zip_longest, and check that the path was existing (is not None)